# I am trying to set values in a bean on instantiation

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to set values in a bean on instantiation on web application.

When the server is first started the values are pulled into the house object.

But when I later instantiate a new house the values are null. How do I set the values on instantiation.

Thanks for any help.

XML

```
<bean name="houseInfor" class="com.test.House">
       <property name="roof" ref="redtiles" />        
       <property name="walls" value="bricks"/>
</bean>
```

Java

```
public class House {
       private String roof;
       private String walls;

       public void setRoof(String roof) {
              this. roof = roof;
       }

       public void setWalls(String walls) {
              this. walls = walls;
       }
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating, when you say _I later instantiate a new house the values are null_ ?

Comment: You shouldn't be newing up instances of house -- just use the one(s) in your application context.

Answer (score 0):

When Spring creates beans, they inject the values `roof` and `walls` based on the `ApplicationContext`.

When you need those beans, Spring gives it to you either by:

- Dependency Injection via `Autowire` or setting property on `Context`.
- `ClassOfBean bean = (ClassOfBean) ApplicationContext.getBean(NameOfBean)` that you call on your method.

When you call `new ClassOfBean()`, Spring doesn't inject its dependencies at it is not related to Spring's instantiation. Thus, you get the `null` values.